# How to generate custom Id from entity properties in EF Core?

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have a scenario that I have to generate an Id based on the two properties of an Entity. For instance:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    public int BarId { get; get; }
    
    public int WafuId { get; set; }
}
```

The Id should be having a value of `{BarId}_{WafuId}`, so it could be `1_1` or `1_2` and should be injected every time a record is created.

I have remove the default value generation from the database by doing the this line of code: `builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();`. And then tried the ValueGenerator

```
public class FooIdValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<string>
{
    public override string Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        var ent = new Foo();
        var barIdPropName = nameof(ent.BarId);
        var wafuIdPropName = nameof(ent.WafuId);
        
        var id1 = entry.CurrentValues[barIdPropName];
        var id2 = entry.CurrentValues[wafuIdPropName];

        return $"{id1}_{id2}";
    }

    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues { get; }
}
```

It does the job, but not sure if this is the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

With the fluent API notation, you can use a computed SQL column like this:

```
 builder.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("[BarId] + '_' + [WafuId]");
```

You can also take a look at this [example](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascomputedcolumnsql-method).

Comment: Hi @citronas would this mean that I do not also need to use the `ValueGeneratedNever()`?

Comment: I've never used `ValueGeneratedNever()` before. The code I posted automatically updates the database automatically without `ValueGeneratedNever()`